# Rewriting to CIImage in Swift eventually causes processor to go down to 0% and freeze

Tags: swift, cpu-usage, freeze, blend, ciimage

I'd like to blend a CIImage to the last CIImage I had. When I repeat this a number of times, the output image eventually freezes and I see the CPU drop to 0%. I'm not sure if it's because it's immutable, but I'm redefining other CIImages without a problem, so I'm not sure if that's the problem.

My CIImage that I'm rewriting to is global, but I've tried all difference scopes. It's also optional

```
var retainedCI:CIImage? = nil
```

My function

```
func createRetainedCI(ciImage:CIImage,
                      retainedCI:CIImage) -> CIImage {

    let colorMatrix = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix")
    colorMatrix?.setDefaults()

    colorMatrix?.setValue(retainedCI, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    colorMatrix?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: debugAlpha), forKey: "inputAVector")

    var dupeCI = colorMatrix?.outputImage

    dupeCI = dupeCI?.applyingFilter("CISourceOverCompositing", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: dupeCI!,
                                                                                kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: ciImage])

    return dupeCI!

}
```

How I'm calling it

```
if retainedCI == nil { retainedCI = ciImage }

retainedCI = hueCycleFilters.createRetainedCI(ciImage: ciImage, retainedCI: retainedCI!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function

```
func createRetainedCI(ciImage:CIImage,
                      retainedCI:CIImage) -> CIImage {

    let colorMatrix = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix")
    colorMatrix?.setDefaults()

    colorMatrix?.setValue(retainedCI, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    colorMatrix?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: debugAlpha), forKey: "inputAVector")

    var dupeCI = colorMatrix?.outputImage

    colorMatrix = nil

    dupeCI = dupeCI?.applyingFilter("CISourceOverCompositing", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: dupeCI!,
                                                                                kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: ciImage])

    return dupeCI!

}
```

Comment: Is the only thing that changed is assigning nil to colorMatrix? That's an error, because colorMatrix is defined with let. I tried changing that to var and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Even if I get rid of colorMatrix and have dupeCI equal retainedCI, I'll still have the same problem.